# How to create and publish Index using Java Client Programatically

Tags: java, indexing, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Is it possible to programmatically create and publish secondary indexes using Couchbases Java Client 2.2.2? I want to be able to create and publish my custom secondary indexes Running Couchbase 4.1. I know this is possible to do with Couchbase Views but I can't find the same for indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

couchbase-java-client-2.3.1 is needed in order to programmatically create indexes primary or secondary. Some of the usable methods can be found on the `bucketManger` same that is used to upsert views. Additionally the static method `createIndex` can be used it support DSL and String syntax

There are a few options to create your secondary indexes.

Option #1:

```
Statement query = createIndex(name).on(bucket.name(), x(fieldName));
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query));
```

Option #2:

```
String query = "BUILD INDEX ON `" + bucket.name() + "` (" + fieldName + ")";
N1qlQueryResult result = bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(query));
```

Option #3 (Actually multiple options here since method `createN1qlIndex` is overloaded

```
bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex(indexName, fields, where, true, false);
```

Comment: what does the 'x' before fieldName mean/do?

Comment: @SuperCow this is from couchbase N1ql DSL. The x method takes any N1ql expression. Have a look at the couchbase java client docs for more details

Comment: Thanks much for the help!

Comment: @MarquisBlount big thank! I used option #2 that created the indices I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Primary index:

```
// Create a N1QL Primary Index (ignore if it exists)
bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlPrimaryIndex(true /* ignore if exists */, false /* defer flag */);
```

Secondary Index:

```
    // Create a N1QL Index (ignore if it exists)
    bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex(
            "my_idx_1",
            true, //ignoreIfExists
            false, //defer
            Expression.path("field1.id"),
            Expression.path("field2.id"));
```

or

```
    // Create a N1QL Index (ignore if it exists)
    bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex(
            "my_idx_2",
            true, //ignoreIfExists
            false, //defer
            new String ("field1.id"),
            new String("field2.id"));
```

The first secondary index (my_idx_1) is helpful if your document is something like this:

```
{
    "field1" : {
        "id" : "value"
    },
    "field2" : {
        "id" : "value"
    }
}
```

The second secondary index (my_idx_2) is helpful if your document is something like this:

```
{
    "field1.id" : "value",
    "field2.id" : "value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with any 2.x, once you have a Bucket

bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(queryString))

where queryString is something like

String queryString = "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON `" + bucketName + "` USING GSI;";

Answer (score 1):

As of `java-client 3.x+` there is a `QueryIndexManager`(obtained via `cluster.queryIndexes()`) which provides an indexing API with the below specific methods to create indexes:

```
createIndex(String bucketName, String indexName, Collection<String> fields)
createIndex(String bucketName, String indexName, Collection<String> fields, CreateQueryIndexOptions options)
createPrimaryIndex(String bucketName)
createPrimaryIndex(String bucketName, CreatePrimaryQueryIndexOptions options)
```